Is there a way for graphql-ruby to return multiple fields on a query?
I'm working on a GraphQL API in Rails. I want to know if queries can have multiple return types.
For instance, I want to return a integer count of people in the lobby. Then, I want to return their associated UserTypes.
{ "users": [Types::UserType], "user_count": Integer

Here's the query:
module Queries
  class FetchLobbyCount < Queries::BaseQuery
    graphql_name "FetchLobbyCount"

    argument :user_id, Integer, required: false

    type Integer, null: false

    def resolve(user_id:)
      @user = User.find(user_id)

      unless @user.present?
        return GraphQL::ExecutionError.new("Cannot find user with id: #{user_id}")
      end

      User.where(awaiting_match: true).where.not(id: user_id).count
    end
  end
end

I've tried using the field keyword to define the return types.

The way you return more data is to define a Type that contains the fields you want to return eg:
module Queries
  class FetchLobbyCount < Queries::BaseQuery
    graphql_name "FetchLobbyCount"

    argument :user_id, Integer, required: false

    type LobbyUsersType, null: false

    def resolve(user_id:)
      @user = User.find(user_id)

      unless @user.present?
        return GraphQL::ExecutionError.new("Cannot find user with id: #{user_id}")
      end

      User.where(awaiting_match: true).where.not(id: user_id).count
    end
  end
end

and then something like:
module Types
  class LobbyUsersType
    description 'Information about users in a given lobby'

    field :lobby_id, Integer, "ID of the lobby we're fetching the users for", null: true
    field :user_count, Integer, "Number of users in this lobby", null: true
    
    # etc...
  end
end

